# Why does the second CREATE OBJECT generate a short dump?

Tags: abap

I have got a following case.

An include with a local interface definition

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&  Include           ZZZ_INCL_INTERFACE
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

INTERFACE lif_test.
  METHODS:
    test.
ENDINTERFACE.                    "lif_test
```

A report which uses this include and defines a class implementing this interface.

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  ZZZ_IMPL_A
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT zzz_impl_a.

INCLUDE zzz_incl_interface.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       CLASS lcl_test_a DEFINITION
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
CLASS lcl_test_a DEFINITION FINAL.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES:
      lif_test.
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_test_a DEFINITION

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       CLASS lcl_test_a IMPLEMENTATION
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
CLASS lcl_test_a IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD lif_test~test.
  ENDMETHOD.                    "lif_test~test
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_test_a IMPLEMENTATION
```

And a second report which also uses this include and defines a new class also implementing the same interface defined in the include.

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  ZZZ_IMPL_B
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT zzz_impl_b.

INCLUDE zzz_incl_interface.

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       CLASS lcl_test_b DEFINITION
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
CLASS lcl_test_b DEFINITION FINAL.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES:
      lif_test.
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_test_b DEFINITION

*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       CLASS lcl_test_b IMPLEMENTATION
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
CLASS lcl_test_b IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD lif_test~test.
  ENDMETHOD.                    "lif_test~test
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_test_b IMPLEMENTATION

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA:
      l_rif_test TYPE REF TO lif_test.

    CREATE OBJECT l_rif_test TYPE ('\PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_B\CLASS=LCL_TEST_B').
    CREATE OBJECT l_rif_test TYPE ('\PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_A\CLASS=LCL_TEST_A').
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

END-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

The line `CREATE OBJECT l_rif_test TYPE ('\PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_A\CLASS=LCL_TEST_A')` generates a short dump saying that the dynamically created object is not an implementation of `lif_test`. Could one explain why it is like that? It looks like a great hole in the language definition. To stop any discussion at the very beginning: No I cannot use dictionary definition of the interface.

EDIT: More descriptive short dump is obtained when trying to cast the instance of the object created by the second `CREATE OBJECT`.

```
DATA:
  l_rcl_object TYPE REF TO object.
*...
CREATE OBJECT l_rcl_object TYPE ('\PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_A\CLASS=LCL_TEST_A').
l_rif_test ?= l_rcl_object.
```

The short dump has it that

```
The content of the source variable does not fit in the target variable.
Source type: "\PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_A\CLASS=LCL_TEST_A"
Target type: "\PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_B\INTERFACE=LIF_TEST"
```

It looks like when I include a local definition of an interface in two places they become a two separate definitions, one of program `ZZZ_IMPL_B` and the second of `ZZZ_IMPL_A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your class A and B definitions and implementations inside separate includes, and include those along with the interface inside the report containing your main class. Like this:

```
report zzz_impl.

include zzz_incl_interface.
include zzz_incl_a.
include zzz_incl_b.

class lcl_main definition final create private.
  public section.
    class-methods:
      main.
endclass.

class lcl_main implementation.
  method main.
    data l_rif_test type ref to lif_test.

    create object l_rif_test type lcl_test_b.
    create object l_rif_test type lcl_test_a.
  endmethod.
endclass.

end-of-selection.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

The reason for the shortdump, is because you're trying to use a variable of the type \PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_**B**\INTERFACE=LIF_TEST to refer to an object which implements \PROGRAM=ZZZ_IMPL_**A**\INTERFACE=LIF_TEST.

---

Edit: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with your comment, but maybe generating the entire report is possible for your use case? For example:

```
report zzz_impl_gen.

data source_interface type standard table of char255.
append `interface lif_test.` to source_interface.
append `  methods:` to source_interface.
append `    test.` to source_interface.
append `endinterface.` to source_interface.

data source_class_a type standard table of char255.
append `class lcl_test_a definition final.` to source_class_a.
append `  public section.` to source_class_a.
append `    interfaces:` to source_class_a.
append `      lif_test.` to source_class_a.
append `endclass.` to source_class_a.
append `class lcl_test_a implementation.` to source_class_a.
append `  method lif_test~test.` to source_class_a.
append `  endmethod.` to source_class_a.
append `endclass.` to source_class_a.

data source_class_b type standard table of char255.
append `class lcl_test_b definition final.` to source_class_b.
append `  public section.` to source_class_b.
append `    interfaces:` to source_class_b.
append `      lif_test.` to source_class_b.
append `endclass.` to source_class_b.
append `class lcl_test_b implementation.` to source_class_b.
append `  method lif_test~test.` to source_class_b.
append `  endmethod.` to source_class_b.
append `endclass.` to source_class_b.

data source_main type standard table of char255.
append `class lcl_main definition final create private.` to source_main.
append `  public section.` to source_main.
append `    class-methods:` to source_main.
append `      main.` to source_main.
append `endclass.` to source_main.
append `class lcl_main implementation.` to source_main.
append `  method main.` to source_main.
append `    data l_rif_test type ref to lif_test.` to source_main.
append `    create object l_rif_test type lcl_test_b.` to source_main.
append `    create object l_rif_test type lcl_test_a.` to source_main.
append `    write: / 'Hello, World!'.` to source_main. " Just to test if it works
append `  endmethod.` to source_main.
append `endclass.` to source_main.

data source_form type standard table of char255.
append `form main.` to source_form.
append `  lcl_main=>main( ).` to source_form.
append `endform.` to source_form.

data source_all type standard table of char255.
append `program subpool.` to source_all.
append lines of source_interface to source_all.
append lines of source_class_a to source_all.
append lines of source_class_b to source_all.
append lines of source_main to source_all.
append lines of source_form to source_all.

data generated_program type string.
data message type string.
data sid type string.
generate subroutine pool source_all name generated_program message message shortdump-id sid.

perform ('MAIN') in program (generated_program) if found. " Important, subroutine name must be in upper case!
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not what I am looking for. What I am trying to do is to write an own Mock Objects framework (pity that SAP has not written one yet), this includes generating a report on the fly an then generating the code inside this report. Therefore the solution provided does not cover my expecations; also because of that I have to create the objects dynamically. For an interface that is defined globally, there is no problem. Right now I am looking for a solution for a local interface.

Comment: Updated the answer as a reply to your comment.

Comment: Nope this is actually the same thing. I am not sure whether you are familiar with Mock Objects concept. I need to create an instance of a class implementing an interface during the code execution. The interface definition is located in an include. What I am trying to do, is to generate an executable report with `INCLUDE ZZZ_INCL_INTERFACE. * dynamically generated code that implements the interface` and then dynamically (using `\PROGRAM=\CLASS=`) create an instance of this class contained in this report from another report (I cannot change the second report on the fly as it is already loaded).

Comment: And some clarification. The class implementing the interface of course does not exist at the moment of execution of the program as it is my mock in this case. I am surprised that the same local interface is not actually the same local interface during the execution even though it is derived from the same include in both reports.

Comment: Why are you surprised by that? It's a local definition... It'd be more surprising if you would be able to access it outside the program where it's supposed to be local ;) Anyway, I don't think it can be done unless you generate everything within the same program.

Comment: +1 for the `subroutine pool` concept as it will simplify some things for me, however it does not solve my problem completely.

Comment: I am suprised because although the interface comes from the same include, including them in two different source actually makes it two different interfaces. Pity in that case is that an include actually works like a macro in `C`.

Comment: Jagger, it looks like you want to generate lots of classes in memory without saving them.  Remember that you can only use GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL 36 times, then you'll have to restart the transaction!

Comment: ...and INCLUDEs in ABAP work just like #include statements in C/C++. Nothing to be ashamed of. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behavior is that INCLUDE does just that - it includes the contents of the include at the point of the INCLUDE statement, which is slightly better than copy&paste from a developer's point of view, but the same thing as far as the system is concerned. You get two interface definitions in distinct programs that are equal, but not identical. One solution might be to generate a report, a subroutine pool, a function pool or a module pool that contains the interface. These program types generate their own loads, so you'll get an interface \PROGRAM=ZZZ_MY_SUBROUTINE_POOL\INTERFACE=LIF_TEST that you can then use from your other programs. Note that you'll still have to write this subroutine pool to the repository, just keeping it locally won't help.

(Other than that, why exactly isn't generating global interface and classes an option?)

Comment: Using global interface is an option in 50% of the cases. If you see my comments below, I want to create a Mock Objects framework for ABAP. Because of that fact it has to be possible to mock global interfaces as well as local ones. The problem I described was an abstraction of a solution that I thought would work for local interfaces. In general what I want to do is to create an implementation of an interface on the fly, create an instance of this dynamically generated class and then use it in the same program (in fact ABAP Unit classes).

Comment: +1 for the `subroutine pool` concept as it will simplify some things for me, however it does not solve my problem completely.

Comment: Jagger, I'm not sure what you mean when you're talking of "mock objects". Maybe I got your intentions totally wrong. However, in almost 10 years of ABAP software development I have yet to see a locally defined interface in some other context than training material or poof-of-concept (typo intended). I think you're trying to find a generalized solution for a problem that doesn't exist. The only things you'll ever want to mock - from my experience - are global interfaces, and to use the mockups - for example in unit tests - you'll need global classes.

Comment: No, not really. I have a lot of code that I write as reports (using local classes) so afterwards I can simply copy paste them to a text file and view them in any moment without an access to a SAP system. This way I have also a possiblity to move this code between different systems without dumping all the stuff into binary transport file and then ask an administrator to load it for me as a transport order in another system. You would be really surprised how many different tools I prepared using this approach and in this manner reused in different projects.

Comment: I'm not surprised - it's copy&paste stuff like that I have to clean up and rework into maintainable products half of the time. In this case, I'm not sure I really want to help you. ;-)